# responsive website html/css problem in images

Tags: html, css

Can you help me with responsive page? Look here http://trenixout.eu/prodej.html
(its for my school project) The box with images make problems... I dont know how to solved this can you help me please someone?

https://upload.hicoria.com/files/g9EpJt6w.png

```css
.background3 {
    background-color: #e8e8e8;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 905px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 20px;
}

.wrapper h1 {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 4px 20px;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 50px;
    box-shadow: -2px 3px 24px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.20);
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}

.veci {
    margin: 20px 0;
}

.vec {
    background-color: #fff;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
    width: 205px;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: 10px 6px 16px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.58);
}

.vec img{
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

.vec h2 {
    font-size: 12p;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    padding: 0 0 10px 0;
}

.vec button {
    border: 1p solid #000;
    padding: 4px 14px;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    flex: right;
    margin: 5px 0;
    font-weight: 400;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 50px;
}

.vec button:hover {
    border: 1p solid #000;
    padding: 4px 14px;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    flex: right;
    margin: 5px 0;
    font-weight: 400;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 50px;
}

.vec button:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.vec span {
    float: right;
}

.vec p {
    font-size: 14px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px){
    .wrapper {
        width: 805px;
        margin: 20px auto;
        padding: 20px;
    }
    .background3 {
        height: 150vh;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px){
    .vec {
        margin: 0 5px 10px 0;
        width: 205px;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    .background3 {
        height: 150vh;
    }
    .wrapper {
        width: 605px;
        margin: 20px auto;
        padding: 20px;
        width: 80%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
    .background3 {
        height: 175vh;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Prodej domů • Prodejdum.cz</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <meta name="author" content="David Laibl">
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="100">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/jpg" href="favicon.ico"/>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Jost:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/d1341f9b7a.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="background3">
            <nav>
                <div class="logo"><h1>ProdejDum.cz</h1></div>
                <div class="menu">
                    <a href="index.html">Domů</a>
                    <a class="active" href="prodej.html">Prodej</a>
                    <a href="onas.html">O Nás</a>
                    <a href="kontakt.html">Kontakt</a>
                    <a href="kvalita.html">Kvalita</a>
                </div>
                <div class="hambac">
                    <div class="line1"></div>
                    <div class="line2"></div>
                    <div class="line3"></div>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <br><br><br>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <h1>Naše aktuální nabídka</h1>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <div class="veci">
                    <div class="vec">
                        <img src="images/dva.png" alt="">
                        <br>
                        <h2>Rodinný dům 4+1</h2>
                        <p>Cena: 2 750 000 Kč</p>
                        <br>
                        <button class="pridat" type="button" autofocus onclick="alert('Produkt byl přidán do košíku.')">Koupit</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="vec">
                        <img src="images/jedna.png" alt="">
                        <br>
                        <h2>Rodinný dům 5+1</h2>
                        <p>Cena: 3 250 000 Kč</p>
                        <br>
                        <button class="pridat" type="button" autofocus onclick="alert('Produkt byl přidán do košíku.')">Koupit</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="vec">
                        <img src="images/tri.png" alt="">
                        <br>
                        <h2>Rodinný dům 5+2</h2>
                        <p>Cena: 4 250 000 Kč</p>
                        <br>
                        <button class="pridat" type="button" autofocus onclick="alert('Produkt byl přidán do košíku.')">Koupit</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="vec">
                        <img src="images/ctyry.png" alt="">
                        <br>
                        <h2>Rodinný dům 6+1</h2>
                        <p>Cena: 4 200 000 Kč</p>
                        <br>
                        <button class="pridat" type="button" autofocus onclick="alert('Produkt byl přidán do košíku.')">Koupit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

"It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."
cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc

Comment: What is your problem? How do you want it to be fixed?

Comment: I dont know  how to make responsive box with images. photo: https://upload.hicoria.com/files/g9EpJt6w.png

Answer (score 0):

if you mean having the images fit full width in smaller screen size you can adjust the width to 100% for the .vec @ 700px

Answer (score 0):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 700px){
.vec {
    margin: 0 5px 10px 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use these classes on your picture's parent
`<div class="col-12>"` for a full width in screen <576px,
`<div class="col-sm-12>"` for a full width in screen ≥576px,
`<div class="col-md-12>"` for a full width in screen ≥768px,
`<div class="col-lg-12>"` for a full width in screen ≥992px,
`<div class="col-xl-12>"` for a full width in screen ≥1200px.
Make sure that all of the pictures are in the same div so that they are responsive no matter what size of your display is and instead of using 12 for a full width, you can youse 6 so that 2 pictures will be displayed in the same line.
For more about column you can check here [Bootstrap Grid System](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)

Answer (score 0):

You may solve your issue with `flex` and remove `float`.

```
.veci {
  /* display: block; */
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.vec {
  background-color: #fff;
  /* float: left; */
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  width: 205px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 10px 6px 16px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.58);
}
```